# How to override class arrow function method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I know this is something simple but I can't seem to find an answer to my question.

Many references that if you have the same function name only the last instance of the function will be called when the function is called (override).

I can't seem to do this if the function is an arrow function.

Normal function behavior:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.something();
  }

  something() {
    console.log('I am A');
  }
}

class B extends A {
  something() {
    console.log('I am B');
  }
}

let b = new B();
```

This does overrides the `something()` function in `class A` but I can't seem to override function `something()` if it is in an arrow function format.

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.something();
  }

  something = () => {
    console.log('I am A');
  }
}

class B extends A {
  something = () => {
    console.log('I am B');
  }
}

let b = new B();
```

Why is the output of the two are different? How can I override the arrow function in the parent class correctly?

Comment: It has nothing to do with arrow functions. You get the same result with `something = function() { ... }`.

Comment: The difference is assignment versus declaration.

Comment: Why would you define an arrow function inside of a class like that? Or is it just because

Comment: @chiliNUT There is this npm package that has an error that declared the function like that. I want to extend to that package then override the function that causes the error as I don't want to edit the package directly.

Comment: Arrow functions should generally not be used as class methods, because they don't get `this` from the object.

Comment: https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1 Here is a good blog on why not to use arrow functions as class methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.something();
  }

  something = () => {
    console.log('I am A');
  }
}

class B extends A {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.something();
  }
  something = () => {
    console.log('I am B');
  }
}

let b = new B();
```

This works for me. What is happening is that you're calling `this.something()` inside of Class A, therefore it will use its own method in Class A. If you call this in class B, it will use it own constructor which overrides Class A constructor. You can also call Class A in Class B by using `super.something();`

Comment: Look at the constructor. It *is* calling the function. Right now, based on that code how it is setup. You should get `I am A` then `I am B`.

Comment: Isn't there a way that only the new function in `class B` will be called? Just like in the example above (normal function)

Comment: Yes..... Remove the method that is being called in `class A` constructor. This is how the code is executed..
Starting with let `b = new B();`
class B create -> extends class A -> class A initalizes and execute `constructor()` function -> class B initalizes -> Overwrites class A method -> and then execute `constructor()` function

Comment: Let me know if I'm asking the impossible. There is this npm package I am using, it has an error in one of its method (that is class A). What I am doing is I created class B to override the method that has an error in the package (class A). So that means I can't edit the (class A) since it is an external package.

Comment: That is correct. You can override the function, which you're already doing, however, you can't override the function before `class A` is initialized in itself. So it is a function inside `class A` that needs to be changed when `class A` is being initialized, then it won't work. However, if you just need to call this method after `class B` is initialized, then it'll work fine.

Comment: @DavidAngulo let me know if I answered your question. If I have, please mark this as the correct answer. If the answer was my last comment, let me know and I will post that in the answer.

Comment: @Matthew This does not seem to work with fat arrow binding: "You can also call Class A in Class B by using super.something()"